# why does EKEventEditViewController take ~3 seconds to load

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, delay, eventkit

I have a `EKEventEditViewController` that I initializie and present like this:

```
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil] autorelease];

[self presentModalViewController: addController animated: NO];
```

I notice that on an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.3 it takes about 3 seconds until the modalView shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to call that from the main tread